# How to Change the Default Displaying Order of Esri Basemaps in basemapGallery?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-online-basemaps, display, order

I just started using ArcGIS JS APIs. In my app, I want to combine a few ESRI basemaps with my own basemap service. I am using basemapGallery dijit to change basemaps. By default, basemapGallery shows the imagery map. I want to show OpenStreetMap as the default. How can I make this happen?

The code in my app is simple and directly borrowed from ArcGIS samples. So I did not put it here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that you'll be best served to create a manual list of the basemaps, including the order, that you want displayed within the gallery.

[This ArcGIS thread](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/47153-Adding-Image-with-Labels-to-BasemapGallery) gives quite a bit of detail into what you might be looking for and some code in how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

You also have the option of moving the div which contains your custom basemap using JavaScript. The following code moves the basemap div to the top of the gallery:

```
on(gallery, "load", function() {
    var nd = document.getElementById("galleryNode_myBasemap");
    nd.parentElement.insertBefore(nd, nd.parentElement.firstElementChild);
}
```

Where "myBasemap" is the ID of the basemap layer and `gallery` is a reference to the Basemap Gallery.

This will work in IE9+, if you need to support IE7+, change `.firstElementChild` to `.firstChild` (although I haven't tested it).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and this is my solution.

```
// Create a basemap order array.

    var bmOrder = ["Imagery","Open Street Map","Topographic","National Geographic","Streets"];

// OnLoad get the info and bind it to gallary basemap

    var mappedBm=[];
    basemapGallery.on("load", function (res) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < bmOrder.length; i++) {
                        for (var j = 0; j < res.target.basemaps.length; j++) {
                            if (bmOrder[i] === res.target.basemaps[j].title) {
                                mappedBm.push(res.target.basemaps[j]);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    // Bind the mapped version.
                    basemapGallery.basemaps = mappedBm;
                });
```